# $.getJSON() is not working with chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome, getjson

This code works fine in FF and IE, but not in Chrome why?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("timline.js",function(result){
     alert(result);
  });
});
```

chrome error: 
Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. file:///E:/jquery/parekh_timeline/timline.js

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///E:/jquery/parekh_timeline/timline.js. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: By the look of the error it's because you're running this via the filesystem, not through a loca server e.g. XAMPP.

Answer (score 2):

It's famous Chrome [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787&q=ajax%20local&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS).

Run local web server and use localhost. I'm using `SimpleHTTPServer` python module:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Or use Chrome flag `--allow-file-access-from-files`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to host your files on a web server.